I can't reproduce input embedded in a contest interface
I solved a contest task but couldn't submit it because I can't reproduce input embedded in the contest interface. Input is defined in 4 strings, each can be empty but has at its end a symbol for line break (I guess "\n"). If not empty the strings consist of 3-lettered weekdays with 1 space between:
MON\n
MON WED\n
\n
FRI THU SUN\n

I've tried:
text = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        text.append(line)
    else:
        break
text = [line.rstrip() for line in text]

But it requires to enter the input a 5th time to make the break-condition work, failing the solution. I'm not sure whether the compiler considers "\n" -only strings as not empty. sys.stdin.readlines() requires CTRL-D after input, so cannot be used. I need the input of 4 strings with "\n" in the end (no matter if they are empty or full), to be put into a list (ideally a list of lists):
[['WED', 'FRI'], ['MON', 'TUE'], [], ['MON', 'WED', 'THU', 'SAT', 'FRI', 'SUN', 'TUE']]  # ideally
['WED FRI', 'MON TUE', '', 'MON WED THU SAT FRI SUN TUE']  # also okay

Also, I checked the input from the contest system in PyCharm's debug console. Either way I entered, it didn't clear the "\n" sign from strings. How to make the debugger understand a "\n"-sign?
MON\n
MON"\n"
MON'\n'
"MON\n"  # neither of them cleared the "\n" from the string.


Create an external file. Run python main.py < input.txt for the four line file

@OneCricketeer, thanks for an advice, but the contest input system doesn't allow to apply files for the input, unfortunately.

That's how the system is likely supplying the input, already. I was saying not to explicitly type the input when you try to run it locally. The code you have looks fine, with the exception of splitting the days

If "Input is defined to be in 4 strings", then you certainly don't want a while loop with an exit condition; use a for loop that executes four times, or simply four input()s each assigned to a variable.

@OneCricketeer, Aaah, got your point. Yes, it can possibly help, but you see, I've tried all this to manage to reproduce the input of the contest system. With my own input my task is solved successfully.

@jasonharper, thank you, that was somehow obvious, but yet... :D Still - and what if not? What if the number of strings is not defined?

As far as I know, there is no way to enter '\n' using the input function.  When you press the enter key or paste the '\n' character at the prompt, the input function terminates returning the characters up to that point but not including the newline character.

There'd have to be SOME explicit indication of the end of input, or the problem wouldn't be solvable.  Terminating on a blank line only works if there cannot possibly be a blank line in the middle of the input.  Other options include a first line of input that gives the number of further lines to read, or reading until a specific string such as "END".

@jasonharper, thank you. After all, it seems it's not me being stupid, it's just impossible without additional enter of input or specification of number of iterations.

What does the contest question actually say about by what method it supplies input to the tested program? Is it through stdin, as a command line argument, something else...?

@CrazyChucky, it doesn't :) Only time (1 sec), size of memory (256 MB), version of compiler (3.10.6) and description I've mentioned above.

If it's not specified in the question itself, I would hope it's a standard rule across questions on whatever site you found it... I've seen code challenge sites, for instance, that expect you to make a function named solution that accepts the input as its argument. If nowhere in the question or the rest of the site does it tell you how it's going to test your code, then I don't know how they expect people to complete the challenges.

@CrazyChucky, well, in this case they usually demand to make input via standard functions.

If I got it right you want to read input from console and store it in a list of lists
in this case since there is always 4 lines of input you could actually do it like this
text = []
for _ in range(4):
    line = [weekday for weekday in input().split()]
    text.append(line)

print(text)

so for example if input in console is
Wed Thu Fri

Sat Sun Mon Tue
Tue Sun

then the value of text which gets printed is [['Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'], [], ['Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue'], ['Tue', 'Sun']]  And if for any reason the number of lines can be actually greater than 4 then in this case it will be necessary to provide the number of lines and so code becomes like this
text = []

num_lines = int(input())
for _ in range(num_lines):
    line = [weekday for weekday in input().split()]
    text.append(line)

print(text)

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Could be simplified to text.append(input().split()) or text = [input().split() for _ in range(4)]

@OneCricketeer i guess since i didn't want it to be a one liner i did like this so it is clear, otherwise the text = [input().split() for _ in range(num_lines)] should do the trick
